# How to have <% f.submit %> redirect to an anchor tag upon submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, submit, ransack

I am trying to create a search filter for my google maps app  using Ransack.  The filtering is woking but I want it to redirect to my #footer where the map is located and not the top of the page.  Is this possible?  Here is what I have

**<%= f.submit "Filter Results", :onsubmit => root_path(:anchor => 'footer'), :class => "btn btn-success" %>**

any thoughts, Thanks so much
-John

Comment: I don't have the answer unfortunately (I have since forgotten the exact incantation for this), but I do know that you want this not on the submit button, but on the form tag.  I believe you can either use the target attribute or the action attribute, or perhaps a combination.  I believe onsubmit also works on the form tag, but as-is I don't think it'll do what you want.  But this is more of an HTML question than rails, methinks, as I'm not sure there's any helpers for that sort of thing (would love to know if I'm wrong).  Anyway, hope that takes you in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure I understand what you are asking exactly, so forgive me if my answer doesn't help.

With html, if you want to point a link to a specific part of a page you can do the following:

Add the name attribute to the particular spot u want to link to, for example:

Now, to link to that particular section of the page, you add "#section1" to the end of your link

So if you add a name attribute to your footer, and add the proper #name to the end of your link, you should be able to have the url point to the footer on the page.

Hope that helps!

Comment: He wants to submit a form to a target on a page, not link to a target on a page.  Sounds like he has the target set up already, but is trying to figure out how to get his form to submit the information to the target/frame on the page, instead of just to the page itself.

Answer (score 0):

Give this a try...

```
<%=  link_to root_url(anchor: "footer") do %>
  <%= f.submit "Filter Results", class: "btn btn-success" %>
<% end %>
```

or

```
<a href="/controller/#footer">
      <%= f.submit "Filter Results", class: "btn btn-success" %>
</a>
```

I hope this helps.